# Applying LinkedList via Method

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I am learning how to use LinkedList recently and it all worked fine but if I use it as direct approach (without using method), it had many errors.

What I want to do is, to read a file text and save it into a LinkedList.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node<String> workflowHead = null;
    Node<String> workflowTail = null;

    try {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("workflow.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            if (i == 0) {
                workflowHead = new Node<String>(in.nextLine());
                workflowTail = workflowHead;
            }
            else {
                workflowTail.next = new Node<String>(in.nextLine());
                workflowTail = workflowTail.next;
            }
            i++;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The above is what I meant by 'direct approach' without using method.

Now, tell me, how do I achieve all of this by using method?

The above code works fine but I need to convert it to method-using code.

I tried it like this but it fails miserably:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Node<String> workflowHead = null;
    Node<String> workflowTail = null;

    workflowHead.read(workflowHead, workflowTail);
} //End of main

public class Method {

public void read(Object head, Object tail) {
    try {
        int i = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("workflow.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            if (i == 0) {
                head = new Node<String>(in.nextLine());
                tail = head;
            }
            else {
                tail.next = new Node<String>(in.nextLine());
                tail = tail.next;
            }
            i++;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One problem comes in when you try to do `head = ...` or `tail = ...` (which won't generate any compile-time errors or errors in your current code, but will once you start extending it to test it). What each of these will do is simply give the *local* variable `head` or `tail` a new value. It won't change `workflowHead` or `workflowTail`.

On a more technical level, when you pass in a Object parameter, both the parameter and the original object will point to the same data. So **modifying** that object will change both. However, when you **reassign** the parameter with `=`, the parameter will now point to a different object while the original will still point to the original object.

What you probably want are class variables rather than method parameters.

Also, `workflowHead.read(...)` won't work because `read` is a member of the `Method` class (probably not ideally named) but `wordflowHead` is of type `Node`.

It may also be a better idea to pass in the file name rather than hard-code it in the method. The 'better' way is passing it in from the command-line, but, for testing purposes, this is not ideal.

**I would probably do something like this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyLinkedList<String> linkedList = new MyLinkedList<String>();
   linkedList.read("workflow.txt");
}

static class MyLinkedList<T>
{
   private Node<T> head = null, tail = null;
   public void read(String filename)
   {
     // ... - you can freely reassign head and tail here
   }

   // I'm assuming this class is defined elsewhere,
   //   but defining it here would likely make more sense
   private class Node<T>
   {
     // ...
   }
}
```

It might be better to put your entire `read` method into the `MyLinkedList` constructor.

**If the above is beyond your current understanding**, this may be more understandable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   read("workflow.txt");
}

static Node<T> head = null, tail = null; // these are class variables
static void read(String filename)
{
   // ...
   Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
   // ... - you can freely reassign head and tail here
}
```

Comment: I did the first one but I got just one problem with this line of code;
    list.read("workflow.txt");

The error says;
cannot find symbol
symbol: method read(String)
location: variable list of type LinkedList<String>

Comment: @e-zardYusof If the code is exactly as written, including the class and method definition, then it should work. You could paste the code to somewhere like https://ideone.com (compiles + runs code) or http://pastebin.com/ and I can take a look if you want.